# draw an image to gtk.DrawingArea?

Tags: python, drawing, pygtk, drawable, paint

I'm writing a PyGtk paint program based on the basic tutorial found [here](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/scribblesimple.py).

Is there any way to add an image to the drawing area so that you can still draw over the image? Like a stamp, or an imported photo for example. I've tried adding a `gtk.Image()` but `gtk.DrawingArea` object has no attribute `add`.

```
self.window = gtk.Window((gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL))
self.window.set_title ("Canvas")
self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
hbox = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
self.window.add(hbox)
self.window.set_resizable(False)

# Create the drawing area
drawing_area = gtk.DrawingArea()
drawing_area.set_size_request(screenWidth-350, screenHeight-100)
hbox.pack_start(drawing_area, True, True, 0)
drawing_area.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to draw the image (as a `gtk.gdk.Pixbuf`, not `gtk.Image`) onto the backing pixmap yourself using [`gtk.gdk.Drawable.draw_pixbuf()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkdrawable.html#method-gdkdrawable--draw-pixbuf). Only container widgets (widgets that can contain other widgets) have an `add()` method, and `gtk.DrawingArea` is not one.

```
pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(image_filename) #one way to load a pixbuf
pixmap.draw_pixbuf(None, pixbuf, 0, 0, x, y, -1, -1, gtk.gdk.RGB_DITHER_NONE, 0, 0)
```

Comment: thanks! That worked perfectly. One more question - I'm trying to draw a series of images onto the pixmap by modifying pixbuf, through a loop(a replay function). I want it to show each successive change to the pixmap, but for some reason it only shows the last image loaded...

Comment: `for i in xrange(1, stepCount):  
     loadFile = 'temp\step' + str(i) + '.png'
     pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(loadFile)
     #refresh window
     hbox.remove(self.drawing_area)
     hbox.add(self.drawing_area)
     time.sleep(0.5)
     print 'temp\step' + str(i) + '.png'`

Comment: If you have a different question, it's better to open a new question - more people will see it and you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: But to answer your question, using `time.sleep()` makes the entire program wait, and so the GUI is frozen during that time as well. That's why your new pixmaps are not drawn. Use `gobject.timeout_add()`: http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--timeout-add

Comment: One more thing, if this answer worked, please click the green checkmark at the left.