# Draw an image on drawing area

Tags: c, gtk, drawing

I am trying to draw an image on a drawing area with no luck.I saw a couple of python examples but I was not able to implement them into c ,which I am using (eg [draw an image to gtk.DrawingArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283788/draw-an-image-to-gtk-drawingarea))

I have already created a Pixbuf variable to store the image I want to draw on the drawing area,but there are no functions like gtk_drawing_area_draw_pixbuf or something related to that.Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make use of [`expose-event`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-expose-event) callback (assuming you are working with Gtk+ 2.0) to draw the pixbuf onto drawing area. There is no `gtk_drawing_area_draw_pixbuf` instead you have [`gdk_draw_pixbuf`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Drawing-Primitives.html#gdk-draw-pixbuf). This has been deprecated in favour of [`gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Cairo-Interaction.html#gdk-cairo-set-source-pixbuf) from version 2.22 onwards. You can call these function in your expose event callback something on these lines (please use them as reference only):
If your Gtk version is < 2.22

```
static gboolean
da_expose (GtkWidget *da, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    (void)event; (void)data;
    GdkPixbuf *pix;
    GError *err = NULL;
    /* Create pixbuf */
    pix = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("/usr/share/icons/cab_view.png", &err);
    if(err)
    {
        printf("Error : %s\n", err->message);
        g_error_free(err);
        return FALSE;
    }
    GdkDrawable *draw = gtk_widget_get_window(da);
    /* Draw pixbuf */
    gdk_draw_pixbuf(draw, NULL, pix, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, GDK_RGB_DITHER_NONE, 0, 0);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Version 2.22 onwards you will have to make use of `cairo` something on these lines:

```
static gboolean
da_expose (GtkWidget *da, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    (void)event; (void)data;
    GdkPixbuf *pix;
    GError *err = NULL;
    /* Create pixbuf */
    pix = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("/usr/share/icons/cab_view.png", &err);
    if(err)
    {
        printf("Error : %s\n", err->message);
        g_error_free(err);
        return FALSE;
    }
    cairo_t *cr;
    cr = gdk_cairo_create (da->window);
    gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, pix, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cr);
    cairo_fill (cr);
    cairo_destroy (cr);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Of course you would have connected to the callback using `g_signal_connect` (say `g_signal_connect (da, "expose-event", G_CALLBACK (da_expose), NULL);`). If you are using Gtk+ 3.0 then you will be making use of [`draw`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-draw) instead of `expose-event`. You can always refer to `gtk-demo`/`gtk3-demo` application which are available to see the samples along with the code. This should be available in the package repository of your distro or you can always get it from source.
Hope this helps!
PS: [This link](http://oss.org.cn/man/develop/GTK+/tutorial/x2472.html) might provide you with some pointers

Comment: Great guess,im using 2.24,and even greater answer as well!I would give you 100 votes up if possible!I was using the "expose-event" signal but guessed cairo wouldn't be needed.Cheers again

Comment: @mini-me: I am sorry, but I am not following Gtk as actively as I once used to. What is it that you are trying to do? Did you check gtk-demo?

Comment: @another.anon.coward I fixed your examples by correcting the return value. Is I understood GTK, return must be `true` to suppress other handlers to be called after your handler. `So return FALSE;` would be wrong and the image will be replaced by background or whatever.

Answer (score 8):

Now GTK-version is GTK+3.0.
If you are using GTK+3.0, please use as follows.

```
// gcc expose.c -o expose `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs`
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static gboolean
on_window_draw (GtkWidget *da, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    (void)event; (void)data;
    GdkPixbuf *pix;
    GError *err = NULL;
    /* Create pixbuf */
    pix = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("/usr/share/icons/cab_view.png", &err);
    if(err)
    {
        printf("Error : %s\n", err->message);
        g_error_free(err);
        return FALSE;
    }
    cairo_t *cr;
    cr = gdk_cairo_create (gtk_widget_get_window(da));
    //    cr = gdk_cairo_create (da->window);
    gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, pix, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cr);
    //    cairo_fill (cr);
    cairo_destroy (cr);
    //    return FALSE;
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *canvas;
    gtk_init (&argc , &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (window,
        50, 50);

    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit) , NULL);
    canvas = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), canvas);
    g_signal_connect (canvas, "draw", (GCallback) on_window_draw, NULL);

    gtk_widget_set_app_paintable(canvas, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, this is coming full-circle. Your example taught me how to get this working in Python! I was missing the `cairo_paint(cr)` bit, and it was also excluded from several answers in Python that I was looking at. Much thanks!